# Transpiling boolean.py package to javascript with Transcrypt

Tags: javascript, python, transcrypt

I would like some help transpiling a relatively simple python package called `boolean.py` (the package does boolean algebra operations) into javascript using transcrypt as my transpiler of choice.

Things I have done so far:

1. Dropped using `inspect` module which seems to not be supported by `transcrypt`
2. Switched to explicit `SuperClassName.__init__()` calls instead of `super(SuperClassName, self).__init__()` in python code because `transcrypt` only supports simple single-case inheritance (and python 3 syntax).

You can find the current code here in [this github branch](https://github.com/all3fox/boolean.py/tree/transcrypt) called `transcrypt`.

Now, the good news is that `boolean.py` is essentially a single `.py` file under `boolean/boolean.py`, everything else is just python project structure. The bad news is that `boolean.py` runs on both `python2` and `python3` and I don't know if that is what causes the current issue that I am about to describe:

Having read the relevant sections of [transcrypt docs](http://www.transcrypt.org/docs/html/index.html), I transpile the file:

```
cd boolean/ && transcrypt boolean.py
```

This gives me a single harmless warning about `basestring` and creates the `__javascript__` folder with `boolean.js` and `boolean.min.js`. So far, so good.

Next to the `__javascript__` folder I create `boolean.html` to test:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">

        <title>transcrypt boolean.py</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="__javascript__/boolean.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

However, when I load `boolean.html` in firefox, the console gives a warning:

```
TypeError: can't assign to properties of (new String("all_feature_namesnested_scopes,generators,division,absolute_import,with_statement,print_function,unicode_literals,barry_as_FLUFL,generator_stop")): not an object
```

Instead, what I am expecting to see is a `boolean` object that has `BooleanAlgebra` subobject. Refer to `hello` and `pong` examples of `transcrypt` to see that it creates `hello` and `pong` objects on `window` accordingly.

Could you help explain what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you considered to create also a ticket at https://github.com/QQuick/Transcrypt ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've spent quite some time trying to get your lib to work with Transcrypt, encountering several issues:

1. The `boolean.py` library uses some modules from the CPython distro, like `__future__` and `unittest` which are not yet available for Transcrypt. This is a problem that can be easily circumvented. You may e.g. back to back test the 
   Transcrypt and the CPython version `boolean.py` by using Transcrypt's autotest facility. Of write a very tuned down version of `unittest` yourself etc.
2. The @property decorator is not yet available. But you can use properties in the non-decorator syntax, as indicated in the docs at http://www.transcrypt.org/docs/html/supported_constructs.html#properties
3. There maybe some errors in your adapted code like the Function constructor calling itself in endless recursion.
4. Some exception types (like `TypeError`) aren't yet implemented in Transcrypt.
5. Transcrypt's `type` function is currently only defined with one parameter, something like `return type(base_class.__name__, (base_class,), {})` will curently not work.
6. It is not possible to overload the `__hash__` operator function in Transcrypt. This is due to the desired interoperability with JavaScript. Something like {'bird': 'egg', 'human': 'baby'} gets compiled in to a JavaScript object literal, facilitating initialisation with object literals as is usual in many JavaScript libraries.
7. The `values ()` method of class `dict` was accidentally skipped. It will be added in the next commit of Transcrypt.

These were the issues I could find. There may be more, but I lack the understanding of `boolean.py` to find them in reasonable time.

End result for me is that I can get it to compile, but I cannot get it to run properly after the start of the parsing phase.

My expectation is that for someone knowing your library well, this can all be solved by doable workarounds, since I've seen no code in your lib that really is beyond reach of Transcrypt.

Transcrypt will never be 100% CPython compatible, because of the requirement that the generated code should be as fast and compact as native JavaScript. But if you encounter clear omissions like `dict.values`they will be added. There are also border cases like `string.isalpha`. As long as they're small functions, I see no reason not to add them. Just add a feature request to the issues at https://github.com/qquick/Transcrypt.

Something like `frozenset`is less likely to be added to the core code, although a contribution of such datastructures in a library would of course be welcome.

Note that you can also insert arbitrary snippets of JavaScript code anywhere, should it be needed.